# How can I get the string value in Optional() in swift, which is followed by nil?

Tags: swift

How can I get the string value in Optional() in swift, which is followed by nil?any other proper way to use this evaluateJavaScript() and get the callback value?

```
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("(function() { return 'this'; })();", 
      completionHandler: {
        result in
        //Handle your variable
        print(result)//(Optional(this), nil)
    })
```

Comment: Read the language guide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `if let` to parse the optional value:

```
if let value = result {
    print(value)
}
```

Comment: webView.evaluateJavaScript("(function() { return 'this'; })();", 
            completionHandler: {
            result in
            //Handle your variable
            if let value = result {
                print(value)
            }
            
        })

I get error, Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type

Comment: Don't answer duplicate questions.  Instead, vote to close them as dupes.